# How do I correct this Uncaught RererenceError in Reactj?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started getting this error when I added the channels array as a way to mock a list of channels in the beginning phases of my application.

index.js:7852 Uncaught ReferenceError: channels is not defined(…)

Here is the App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let channels = [
    {name: 'Hardware Support'},
    {name: 'Software Support'}
];

class Channel extends React.Component {
    onClick(){
        console.log('I was clicked', this.props.name);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.name}</li>
        )
    }
}

export default Channel
```

Here is the main.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Channel from './App';

class ChannelList extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.channels.map(channel => {
                        return (
                            <Channel name={channel.name} />
                        )
                    }
                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

class ChannelForm extends React.Component{
    onChange(e){
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }
    onSubmit(e){

    }
    render(){
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <input type='text' onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
            </form>
        )
    }
}

class ChannelSection extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ChannelList channels={channels}/>
                <ChannelForm />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ChannelSection />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Do you expect `channels` in `main.js` to refer to the `channels` variable in `App.js`? If so you have to export it from `App.js` and import it in `main.js`. Or defined `channles` in `main.js` instead of `App.js`. This has nothing to do with React in particular btw, that's simply how JavaScript modules work.

Comment: Felix, thank for your help. Please go ahead and post your answer in such a way that I can check it off as the correct one. Also, I was simply making it clear I was working on an Reactjs app, not so much that it had something to do with React. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @FelixKling, the `channels` variable isn't available to your `main.js` file, as it's not being exported from `App.js`.  The simplest way to share this across both files would be to export is as a *non-default* export, then pull it in as part of your `Channels` import in `Main.js`

Like so:

```
// App.js
let channels = [
    {name: 'Hardware Support'},
    {name: 'Software Support'}
];

...

export channels; // this is the variable export
export default Channel; // this is the class export, which will be the default if no specific export is declared in your import

// Main.js
import Channel, { channels } from './App';
// `Channel` class is imported as usual, along with non-default `channels` export
```

You should also use `const` instead of `let` in your `channels` declaration, as you're not reassigning it.

`const channels = ...`